# Django memcashed does not cache the page

Tags: django, memcached

Ok , so here is what i did so far.

1. Installed memcached through pip install.
2. Added this to settings.py

> ```
>   CACHES = {
>     'default': {
>         'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
>         'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211', 
>     }
>   }
> ```

1. Then put a decorator `@cache_page(60*15)` on a view i want to cache, but nothing changed. If i put time on a page, it updates every refresh , and if i add something to page through form it also appears as soon as it is added ... Based on that info i conclude it does not cache the page.

Basically my parser adds every 3 hours new information , so i need to cash 1 time in 3 hours , exactly after parser insert all the data to the database. Did not figure how to do that yet, as even simple @cache_page does not work .

**Maybe i messed something with configuring memcached ?**

Comment: did you install memcached on your os? is it running at :11211? I think the pip packages are just clients?

Comment: can u try 'telnet localhost 11211' and have u installed python-memcached

Comment: Yeah , i wrote the question and figured it out ..... i did not install memcached on OS, did not understand that it was like a service... Write your answer like a POST , and i'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @dm03514 go for it since you commented first...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

memcached server needs to be installed on your OS.  I think the pip packages are just clients